# Assistant 1.0 Malicious app cannot uninstall or delete.

Tags: malware, uninstallation

[image: Assistant 1.0 open with System Info for Android]!

Is there any other way to remove this app without preforming a factory wipe?

And

Can I still trust my SD Card?

Even Hornet Antivirus is foiled by this app. It's permissions never showed. Even before I disabled this non-manual DL, it was hidden to all but Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Are you rooted? If you are you can remove the app in  multiple ways provided you first have:

1. ADB (Download standalone version to PC - )
2. USB Debugging enabled on phone (Settings->Applications->Development and check USB Debugging).
3. A PC (I will be giving windows instructions but it should carry accross the platforms) and USB cable (apparently type C works best).

Next, connect your phone to your PC and ensure the correct drivers are installed to do so (these can usually be found on your manufacturers webpage).

Launch cmd and navigate to the folder containing adb (using 'cd [filepath]').

Enter the following commands into the command line:

1. > adb devices

If nothing shows here the drivers arent installed correctly or USB Debugging hasn't been enabled.

2. > adb shell

The interface my slightly change now, this is just accessing your phones internal commandline.

3. > cd system/app

Changes directory to system apps.

4. > ls

Find the app you want to remove on this list.

5. > rm example.apk

I would now reccomend rebooting when you are sure the app has been removed.

If you are not rooted try use one-click solutions so you do not have to factory reset your device such as kingroot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a ZTE made device, do not fear, as this is a legitimate app made by ZTE. They don't use it for anything and it's just there.

But if your device is not a ZTE, try to uninstall all of your antivirus apps and install Malwarebytes and Avast Security instead as they are reputable and Hornet antivirus is not.

Comment: Since the package name contains ZTE, I'm thinking the same as you do; however, as for "they don't use it for anything and it's just there", I'd love to see some evidence to back it up - you got any? P.S. I'm Chinese myself but I don't really trust built-in apps by local manufacturers either.

Comment: Don't worry about it being spyware. I have a ZTE phone and the screen above is exactly the same as mine and I read the terms and they can't share the data from the app